# Android BitmapFactory.decodeResource takes too much memory

Tags: java, android, image, memory, bitmap

I have question about loading Bitmap from resources. My code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (mainButton == view) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    }
}
```

The test.jpg image resolution is 3288 x 4936px. It is jpeg (3,9MB / 48,7MB when uncompressed). While this function work (on my Nexus 7 2013 device), following exception occurs:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 259673100 byte allocation with 5222644 free bytes and 184MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:467)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:497)
        at pl.jaskol.androidtest.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Why application tries to allocate as much as 248MB?
I wrote similar application in Qt for Android with the same image in resources and it works OK.

**EDIT:**

1. I can not resize it.
2. This is very simple application, like hello world. It does nothing else, just loads bitmap from resources.

**EDIT2:**

Jim's solution works for me. But there is another problem. After bitmap loading it is 4 times too big (2 times height and 2 times width). I've tried various images, including new image created in Pinta or Gimp.

Comment: Try applying some `Options` on it to change the sample size when generating the bitmap.

Comment: Well that image "only" needs about 64MB (which will fail on almost every phone anyway).  You must be using a lot more memory somewhere else.  Please add the relevant code.  Interestingly, the memory request which failed is for exactly 4 times the bitmap.

Comment: I can not resize it. I have to modify it and save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I resolved my problem in two steps:

1) According to Jim's answer I've added

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

on my application tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

2) Image has been automatically resized because of high `DPI` of screen on my device. To avoid this I had to set *inScaled* option to *false*:

```
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.test, options);
```

Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: This solution is incorrect. You have memory leaks in your app. This solution will only delay the problem but will not fix the leaks. Try to find your issue with the library "LeakCanary"

Comment: @MartinVonMartinsgrün why do you say so? Allocation of 259673100 bytes is not memory leak - that size matches perfectly the image with scale factor=2

Answer (score 6):

You can use `android:largeHeap="true"` on your application tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to go over the `64MB` limit. This wont work on `pre 3.0` devices.

That might fix your problem right there.  If that's still not enough you can load the bitmap using native code where your heap limit is the full memory on the device.  The `NDK` is more involved so try the above solution first.

Comment: This only gives a maximum of 256MB, about the size of the OPs single request.  On many devices, you will only get 64MB or 128MB.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this resource: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Especially `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource` method.

Comment: Unfortunetely, I have to load file in its full resolution.

Comment: Then you will need to use the NDK.  All Java objects are created on the heap.